# sorting integer or decimal column in nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I am trying to sort decimal or integer column. but while sorting ascending zero is coming last.

the code is:

```
criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Decimal,  Projections.Property("cloumn1")))));
```

output:

```
35342860
36870852
87654321
213123213
0
0
```

Any issue in code? or what is solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are most likely null values.  You could look at using a conditional restriction or making this a non nullable column with a default of 0, which would seem to be what you are after.

Conditional restriction would be something like this

```
.AddOrder
    (
        Order.Asc
        (
            Projections.Conditional
            (
                Restrictions.IsNull("cloumn1"),
                Projections.Constant(1),
                Projections.Constant(0)
            )
        )
    )
```

which if you put in as first ordering will put the nulls at the top and displayed as 0

Comment: i understand nulls are not taken into account while sorting. so only null fields are showing always last. for the colum1 i have mapping in fluent nhibernate. i changed column1 data type from int => int?, decimal => decimal? in mapping class . it makes sense. thank you.